# How to 301 redirect subdirectory excluding inner pages?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i would like to make a 301 redirect that only affects the home of a subdirectory, example:
From domain.com/old/ to domain.com/new/
But leave all urls inside domain.com/old/ not redirecting.
Example:
domain.com/old/hello.html doesn't redirect anywhere just 404.

Is this possible? What i have now is:
Redirect 301 domain.com/old domain.com/new

Which works for the home page but also redirects all inner pages which i need to 404,  i only want the home of this subdirectory to redirect.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `/old/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ /new/ [L,R=302]
```